# Return a single value from a consumer-generator

Tags: python, generator

I've got a pipeline of consumer generators. From the last of these consumers, I want to return a result at some point in time. This works:

```
class StopIterationWithResult(StopIteration):
    def __init__(self, result):
        super(StopIterationWithResult, self).__init__()
        self.result = result

# for definition fo consumer decorator see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/
@consumer
def waitfor3():
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        if value == 3:
            raise StopIterationWithResult('Hello')

c = waitfor3()
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print 'calling', i
        c.send(i)
    except StopIterationWithResult as r:
        print 'stopped', r.result
        break
```

Is there a better way? Can you, for example, access the returned value of a generator, if it raises `StopIteration` because of a `return` statement?

As requested by @alexis, here's an example with a pipeline:

```
class StopIterationWithResult(StopIteration):
    def __init__(self, result):
        super(StopIterationWithResult, self).__init__()
        self.result = result

@consumer
def add1_filter(consumer):
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        consumer.send(value+1)

@consumer
def waitfor3():
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        print 'got', value
        if value == 3:
            raise StopIterationWithResult('Hello')

c = waitfor3()
f = add1_filter(c)
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print 'calling', i
        f.send(i)
    except StopIterationWithResult as r:
        print 'stopped', r.result
        break
```

And here's the same with the answer by @Martijn Pieters - makes the filter a bit more ugly, though:

```
@consumer
def add1_filter(consumer):
    result = None
    while True:
        value = (yield result)
        result = consumer.send(value+1)

@consumer
def waitfor3():
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        print 'got', value
        if value == 3:
            yield 'Hello'
            break

c = waitfor3()
f = add1_filter(c)
r = None
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print 'calling', i
        r = f.send(i)
    except StopIteration:
        print 'stopped', r
        break
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just yield the last object after `value=3` and then raise a regular `StopIteration`.

Comment: Can you give an example _with_ a pipeline? It's hard to suggest an improvement without something to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Yield goes both ways. Used in a right-hand expression, it'll receive, and used as a statement it yields the result of the expression.

Just yield that result value:

```
def waitfor3():
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        if value == 3:
            yield 'Hello'
            break

c = waitfor3()
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print 'calling', i
        result = c.send(i)
    except StopIteration:
        print 'stopped', result
        break
```

Comment: Unaccepted the answer after realizing that it needs a modification of the filter. In the hope that there is a better answer.

Comment: And it doesn't work unless you feed one more value than actually needed. (Try with range(4) instead of range(10)) or just notice that it prints "calling 4", too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass `StopIteration`, you can access the `args` you passed to it's constructor. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException:

```
@consumer
def add1_filter(consumer):
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        consumer.send(value+1)

@consumer
def waitfor3():
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        print 'got', value
        if value == 3:
            # This doesn't work:
            # return 456 # SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator 
            # But this does:
            raise StopIteration(123)

c = waitfor3()
f = add1_filter(c)
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print 'calling', i
        f.send(i)
    except StopIteration as r:
        print 'stopped (StopIteration)', r, type(r.args[0])
        break
```